# SAML2.0 SSO with the WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: java, wso2, single-sign-on, saml

I need to use WSO2 Identity server with SAML for SSO for my internal application. I came across this beautiful
[SAML2.0 SSO with the WSO2 Identity Server article](http://sureshatt.blogspot.in/2012/08/saml20-sso-with-wso2-identity-server.html?showComment=1424595697432#c4061858047437030318)

But i have two questions on this article which i am not sure how works

1) In 5th step it is  said "Now the user is being redirected to IDP again. Now the IDP realize this user is already authenticated hence it would issue 
a SAML Assertion without prompting any authentication challenge."

**How will the IDP realize that user is already authenticated ?**

As per my understanding it must be done based on session. Does it mean when authentication request goes from service provider 1 to  Identity server (SP1 redirects the request to IS thru browser ), IS will first authenticate the credentials and if successful keep the user object under session.

Now when second authentication request goes to IS thru SP2, same session ID is sent (provided request is sent from another of same browser), IS fins already a user object associated with this session, so trust him. Is this understanding correct?

2)In step 2 it is said that " Now the SP1 can validate the SAML Assertion issued by IDP and let the user log-in. "
what is the specific field/value (under SAML response sent by IP) , SP1 will verify?

3) Where user credentials are stored. Is it on  IS side or Service provider side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just explain how it works with WSO2IS 5.0.0

1. When user is authenticated to IDP by providing credentials. WSO2IS creates an authenticated session for user and cookie with is associated with the authenticated session set in to the user's browser. Cookie name would be `commonAuthId`.  you can also find it in your browser once you are authenticated with WSO2IS using SSO.  Then user is trying to access another SP using same browser,  cookie would be sent in to the WSO2IS and it identifies  that there is an authenticated session related to the cookie.
2. Usually,  SP validates the SAML2 Response and Assertion. There are several validations that you can do.  But most common would be

   - Signature of the SAML2 Response and SAML2 Assertion
   - Validity period  SAML2 Response and SAML2 Assertion.
   - Audience restriction validation in SAML2 Assertion
   - Destination url and Recipient value

Normally Username would be extracted from the Subject identifier value. Also there may be attributes in the attribute statement, which SP can retrieve and do some validation over them as well.

3. End users are authenticated to the IDP.  So credentials must be in IDP not with the SP. It is one of idea of SSO.  Maintains the credentials in one place.  WSO2IS is default shipped with LDAP based user store.  Therefore end user credentials are stored in the LDAP server. However WSO2IS can be deployed with any existing user stores that you like

Comment: Thanks Asela.  More to clarify
Question on first point explaination.Does WSO2 internally use tomcat as webserver ? If yes probably it does not have to create separate cookie with name 
commonAuthId. jseessionId should be fine . Is n't it?  Second question is cookie will be sent only if request is sent
from tab of same browser. What if request is sent from new window ?

Comment: Question on second point explaination. you said one validation can be "Signature of the SAML2 Response and SAML2 Assertion ". Does it Service provider will keep the signature somewhere in property file . Also whats the main difference between SAML2 Response and SAML2 Assertion ? Are not they same?

Comment: Yes..  it runs on Tomcat... WSO2IS management console is deployed as web app in Tomcat... if you login to management console , It creates a Tomcat session...  But tomcat session is not used for SSO authenticated users...  WSO2IS creates separate little session object for SSO authenticated users. Therefore it generate cookie to be not confused with others....  It depends on browser... i guess it would be sent if you one in new window.. however commonauthid cookie would be expired when browser is  closed

Comment: Not same...   Signature is verified with against  the public key of the signer. Therefore public key must be in the SP side...

Comment: Oh looks like i need to add public key in cacert file. is it? Could you tell in brief whats the diff b/w SAML2 Response and SAML2 Assertion ? probably i am asking too much but i am not getting whats the logical difference.

Comment: Yes.. in to the trust store of the Web app..   As you know, SAML2 SSO is a standards.. So everything has been implemented based on it..  Line 381 http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf  describes on it...   SAML defines a request/response protocol... If you send SAML2 Request to IDP, IDP generates a SAML2 Response.... Simply inside the SAML Response,  it can carry a SAML Assertion as well..

Comment: see if you have thought about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668523/configure-wso2-is-server-to-send-token-in-pre-configured-format-instead-of-saml