# configure WSO2 IS server to send token in pre-configured format instead of SAML response?

Tags: java, wso2, single-sign-on, saml, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity management server(WSO2 IS) for SSO . Once user is authenticated ID server sends the SAML response to
webapp. I want WSO2 IS to send token in pre-configured format(like user_name and user_role) to be sent  instead of  SAML reponse.

Comment: You need to sent something other than SAML2 Response.. As an example  username as  query parameter in POST body ?

Comment: Yes i need to send usern_ame + user_role as response instead of SAML2 response. Can we configure WSO2 server to do this?

Comment: AS i know, It is not possible by default..  because it has been implemented based on SAML2 SSO spec..   if you need to do like above,  customization may be needed...  but i am not sure exact place to change it...  need to go through wso2 code based and find out

Comment: can we do it either oauth or OpenId instead of Saml ?

Comment: Yes.. then you can do it with openid connect.. then you will received a ID Token.. it is a JSON ..   http://soasecurity.org/2015/01/08/openid-connect-identity-server/

Answer (score 1):

WSO2IS acts according to the SAML2 SSO specification, Therefore username and user's attributes can be found inside the SAML2 Assertion as attribute statement. There is no flexibility to customize it.

But, if you do not like SAML2 SSO (As SAML is XML based),  you can use openid connect to achieve the  SSO with WSO2IS.  Then you need to communicate according to the openid connect specification.  WSO2IS support for it and you can find more details from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2015/01/08/openid-connect-identity-server/)

Comment: Thanks i will look into them and will get back to you.